# performance stringbuf vs string

Tags: c++, string

When we have to work with string manipulation, is there any significants performance difference between std::string and std::stringbuf, and if yes why.

More generally when it is good to use std::stringbuf over std::string ?

Comment: I would actually ask the other way around: why the heck use `stringbuf` when `string` has many more methods available, masochism ? I suppose you come from Java or C# with their StringBuilder class work-around...

Comment: @MatthieuM.: no I am a C++ programmer, but yes why ostringstream use stringbuf internally instead of string

Comment: That is completely different. All classes deriving from `ostream` use a buffer that derives from [streambuf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/streambuf/), therefore `stringbuf` is just a wrapper around `string` that inherits from `streambuf` so it can be used there. Typical application of the Adapter or Bridge pattern.

Comment: Rereading myself... The question surprised me a lot as I could not understand why you would come up with it, but it appears that the expression of my surprise may be taken for harshness or beating. If so, I apologize. Asking questions when in doubt is a good way to progress.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `std::stringbuf` uses a string internally to buffer data, so it is probably a bit slower. I don't think the difference would be significant though, because it basically just delegation. To be sure you'd have to run some performance-tests though.

`std::stringbuf` is useful when you want an IO-stream to use a string as buffer (like `std::stringstream`, which uses a `std::stringbuf` by default).

Comment: The question is still unanswered: _is there any __significand__ performance difference_. Following your logic: `std::string` internally uses `char` arrays, so no, you should just stick with `char` arrays.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, a `std::stringbuf` does *not* necessarily (or even ordinarily) use an `std::string` for its internal storage. For example, the standard describes initialization from an `std::string` as follows:

> Constructs an object of class basic_stringbuf ... Then copies the content of
>   str into the basic_stringbuf underlying character sequence [...]

Note the wording: "character sequence" -- at least to me, this seems to be quite careful to avoid saying (or even implying) that the content should be stored in an actual string.

Past that, I think efficiency is probably a red herring. Both of them are fairly thin wrappers for managing dynamically allocated buffers of some sort of character-like sequence. There's a big difference in capabilities (e.g., `string` has lots of searching and insertion/deletion in the middle of a string that are entirely absent from `stringbuf`). Given its purpose, it might make sense to implement `stringbuf` on top of something like a `std::deque`, to optimize the (usual) path of insertion/deletion at the ends, but this is likely to be insubstantial for most uses.

If I were doing it, I'd probably be most worried by the fact that `stringbuf` is probably only tested along with `stringstream`, so if I used it differently than `stringstream` did, I might encounter problems, even if I'm following what the standard says it should support.

Answer (score 0):

`std::stringbuf` extends `std::string` container, for reading and writing to `std::string`.

Generally, there is no significant performance difference between `std::string` and `std::stringbuf`.

Because `std::streambuf` <- `std::stringbuf`, both because:

```
typedef basic_stringbuf<char> stringbuf;    
typedef basic_string<char> string;
```

Read [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringbuf/) for more details.